# Is it possible to use SFML with the Android NDK?

Tags: android, sfml

I've started using SFML recently and I absolutely love it. I'd like to make games that could be ported to android, linux, mac and windows, but it seems that SFML lacks portability.

I've searched for a while and I've only found unrelated or unanswered questions on forums.

Does anyone know of any way to use SFML with the android NDK or any plans to support it in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked this few months ago, the answer is : not at the moment. It's possible but it requires some changes. Currently there is a rewriting for the 2.0 release so maybe after it's done it will be possible to add this.

As it's an open-source project I guess if there is a simple way to help the SFML author, you could propose a patch once 2.0 is done.

source : http://www.sfml-dev.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2503