# How to setup a Visual Studio 2015 Android C++ project to use SFML and targets an Android device?

Tags: c++, android, sfml, visual-studio

In Visual Studio I have installed the cross platform tools to set up a C++ project for Android and iOS such as the Android SDK, NDK and the corresponding USB drivers required to debug the program on a connected android device as well as varying sdk levels allowing for compilation on devices from different periods in time. My first question is: using the default C++ application template in visual studio for android:

[image]

How would I go about rendering an sfml window to the screen of the device I am debugging on within the project’s main function code?:

```
void android_main(struct android_app* state) {
struct engine engine;

memset(&engine, 0, sizeof(engine));
state->userData = &engine;
state->onAppCmd = engine_handle_cmd;
state->onInputEvent = engine_handle_input;
engine.app = state;

// Prepare to monitor accelerometer
engine.sensorManager = ASensorManager_getInstance();
engine.accelerometerSensor = ASensorManager_getDefaultSensor(engine.sensorManager,
    ASENSOR_TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
engine.sensorEventQueue = ASensorManager_createEventQueue(engine.sensorManager,
    state->looper, LOOPER_ID_USER, NULL, NULL);

if (state->savedState != NULL) {
    // We are starting with a previous saved state; restore from it.
    engine.state = *(struct saved_state*)state->savedState;
}

engine.animating = 1;

// loop waiting for stuff to do.

while (1) {
    // Read all pending events.
    int ident;
    int events;
    struct android_poll_source* source;

    // If not animating, we will block forever waiting for events.
    // If animating, we loop until all events are read, then continue
    // to draw the next frame of animation.
    while ((ident = ALooper_pollAll(engine.animating ? 0 : -1, NULL, &events,
        (void**)&source)) >= 0) {

        // Process this event.
        if (source != NULL) {
            source->process(state, source);
        }

        // If a sensor has data, process it now.
        if (ident == LOOPER_ID_USER) {
            if (engine.accelerometerSensor != NULL) {
                ASensorEvent event;
                while (ASensorEventQueue_getEvents(engine.sensorEventQueue,
                    &event, 1) > 0) {
                    LOGI("accelerometer: x=%f y=%f z=%f",
                        event.acceleration.x, event.acceleration.y,
                        event.acceleration.z);
                }
            }
        }

        // Check if we are exiting.
        if (state->destroyRequested != 0) {
            engine_term_display(&engine);
            return;
        }
    }

    if (engine.animating) {
        // Done with events; draw next animation frame.
        engine.state.angle += .01f;
        if (engine.state.angle > 1) {
            engine.state.angle = 0;
        }

        // Drawing is throttled to the screen update rate, so there
        // is no need to do timing here.
        engine_draw_frame(&engine);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use SFML with the Android NDK?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19978/is-it-possible-to-use-sfml-with-the-android-ndk)

Comment: Not really - as SFML does appear to work on Android as demonstrated by this link: https://blog.hig.no/gtl/2015/10/01/howto-sfml-on-android/. There are others on the net. It was more of a question of is it possible to use SFML in a cross platform application in Visual Studio targeted at Android devices and using C++ and if so - what steps would be involved in setting up such a project.